# I got bad output in selecting value from DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

when I using DataGridViewComboBox I can't set value to it to select another display member programmatically
and this is my code

```
            Column3.DataPropertyName = "ColID";
            Column3.Name = "ComboColumn";
            Column3.DisplayMember = "ColName";
            Column3.ValueMember = "ColID";
            Column3.DataSource = myTable;
            Column3.ValueType = typeof(Int32);

            object[] obj = new object[dataGridView1.ColumnCount];
            obj[Column1.Index] = "Ahmed";
            obj[Column2.Index] = "Mohamady";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(obj);

           dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[Column3.Index].Value = 21;
```

and the result is

[image]

Although there are the data in the combo box

[image]

any one can help me ??

Comment: What behaviour do you expect by writing `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[Column3.Index].Value = 21`?

Comment: I expect combobox will display the string how have code 21 I need to set the key value and the combo select the items that have the same value

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand, what you're really trying to do here. What do you mean by "string, that have code 21"?

Comment: In the data table the ColID = 21 when ColName = "Ahmed Mohamady"
and the column binding with this data table when I select The Display value I found the value = 21 But I need to select the display value by passing the code value, It Not working, you got it now ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[Column3.Index].Value = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[Column3.Index]).Items[0];
```

If you need to set one of the values that already exists in `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, you have to use `Items` property, which contains them.

Comment: sorry it not working it's display "System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: I need to set the key value and the combo select the items that have the same value

Comment: @ahmedmohamady I've just made an edit, it should be `Column3` instead of `Column1` in your case.

Comment: yes i know,
and I am already made this change when I make test, 
and it not working :(